# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always returns false even after successfully logged in using PasswordSignInAsync in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Whenever i hit Login the user is Signed in using signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync and result.Succeeded is true. The problem is that if i Call Login second time the user does not presist. User.Identity.IsAuthenticated should be true next time but it is always false

```
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        try
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are alredy Logged In...................");
                var claims = User.Claims;
                return Ok("Authenticated");

            }
            else
            {


                var result = await signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync("myEmail.com", "Password", true, true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Logged in successfully....");

                }
                return Ok("Logged in successfully ");
            }


        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("........................................" +e.Message);
            return Ok(e.Message);
            throw;
        }


    }
```

ConfigureServices in StartUp.Cs looks like

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<DbContextBase>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContextBase>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

and Configure Method in Startup.cs looks like:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

The Login Method must return "Authenticated" when hit second time.

Comment: How did you know user is authenticated or not using cookie  or something ?

Comment: i am using asp.net core identity. i am not sure it is cookie base or something else i am new to idenitity @TonyNgo

Comment: Have you confirmed that a cookie has been set in the browser? What do the logs look like when the second request is made? You should see it talk about authenticating with cookies, etc, in the logs.

Comment: i am testing through postman

Comment: is it neccessory to send request through browser ? can you tell me identity works on cookies

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to configure the actual authentication method, such as cookies.

Use something like this in your `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```